# find all common patterns (substrings) from two files efficiently

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for algorithm which will extract all common patterns from files, the naive algorithm takes O(n^2). To find out all common pattern I need to generate all sub-strings and check it in another given file. I am looking for some data structure or algorithm so that there will be no require to generate all sub strings.Is there any efficient and elegant algorithm for the same.

For the sake of simplicity we will consider file as string. Lets say we have to string str1 = "xxabcyy" and str2="sydabcdy" so the expected out put is {"abc","y"}. The naive method is compare each substring of str1 with str2.For example I have all possible sub strings of str1 i.e. {"x","xx","xxa","xxab","xxabc","xxabcy","xxabcyy","xa","xab",..} then check each of this sub string is in str2 or not.

Comment: anyway karp-rabin can does the same thing better in O( |s| + |t| )

Comment: @Roylee I know karp-rabin has O( |s| + |t| )  but in my case the question is ti find out common pattern I need generate to all subtrings and match with another given file, pattern matching is later stage. I am looking for some data structure or algorithm so that I there will be no require to generate all sub strings.

Comment: "To find out common pattern I need generate to all sub-strings", I don't quite understand this, perhaps you want to rephrase it :)

Comment: @Roylee To find out common pattern I need to generate all possible sub-strings. For the sake of simplicity we will consider file as string. Lets say we have to string str1 = "xxabcyy" and str2="sydabcdy" so the expected out put is {"abc","y"}. The naive method is compare each substring of str1 with str2.For example I have all possible sub strings of str1 i.e. {"x","xx","xxa","xxab","xxabc","xxabcy","xxabcyy","xa","xab",..} then check each of this sub string is in str2 or not.

Comment: ya, it's better when you have example to your question, perhaps you might want to rephrase your question, atm it's fuzzy and hard to understand, hence the downvote from others.

Comment: @Roylee Yes, you can say commonalities in form of list

Comment: One thing you can do to improve speed in the general case is to take advantage of the fact that if "xxa" doesn't exist in the string, then for sure "xxab" isn't going to appear. Of course, if the two strings are identical, this isn't going to help you at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check Apriori and FPGrowth algorithms

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Frequent_Pattern_Mining/The_FP-Growth_Algorithm

Used in market basket analysis and general common pattern analysis